# buscador de imágenes alojadas en el explorador de archivos de un host local

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una equipo con millones de imágenes, con nombres XXXXXX.X, entonces estoy realizando una aplicación con html, php, js, que me permita buscar por nombre, si el usuario ingresa 123456 y presione buscar, realice la operación y traiga los nombres de las imágenes 123456.1, 123456.2, 123456.3, etc y bueno, esto es posible? la forma es la correcta? y si si, me pueden orientar?

Este codigo trae y muestra las imágenes

```
<?php
$directory="//10.133.83.23/mdc/imagenes/";
$dirint = dir($directory);
$archivo = 'l.2';
while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
{
if (!preg_match("jpg", $archivo)){
echo 'img src="file:'.$directory."".$archivo.'" width="100" height="50"';
}
}
$dirint->close();
?>
```

Comment: Lee por favor [ask], edita y muestra dudas claras, así como un avance que le permita a la comunidad identificar que llevas hecho y donde requieres apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero usar [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) devuelve una **matriz** que contiene los ficheros/directorios coincidentes, una matriz vacía si no hubo ficheros coincidentes o **FALSE** si se produjo un error.

Teniendo como base el siguiente listado de archivos:

```
bar.txt       
baz           
foo.txt       
link2foo.txt 
imagen1.jpg
imagen2.jpg
...
```

Bien supongamos que deseo retornar todos los archivos tipos **txt** mi código será:

```
$files = glob("/path/al/directorio/*.txt");
```

lo que hará esto sera retornar un **array** con las coincidencias de mi busqueda sea por la extensión en este caso o por nombre:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /path/al/directorio/bar.txt
    [1] => /path/al/directorio/foo.txt
    [2] => /path/al/directorio/link2foo.txt
)
```

con esto ya puedes realizar lo deseado para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la respectiva documentación.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!